# PowerBI Embed token request return error "Invalid role provided"

Tags: c#, .net, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I try to make request for embed token using .NET client. For it I also pass GenerateTokenRequest with `username`, `datasets` and `roles`

```
var rls = new EffectiveIdentity(username, new List<string> { dataset.Id }, roles);
                        
var generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "view", identities: new List<EffectiveIdentity> { rls });

tokenResponse = await client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroupAsync(workSpaceId, report.Id, generateTokenRequestParameters);
```

In result I receive error "Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'"

```
{"error":{"code":"InvalidRequest","message":"Invalid role provided"}}
```

Does it mean I need to provide roles that only is counter on PowerBI platform? As I just select all roles of logged in user and passing them into request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The roles are defined in your report (see [Define roles and rules in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls#define-roles-and-rules-in-power-bi-desktop) section in [Row-level security (RLS) with Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls)). It looks like you are passing a non-existent role in this list.

Comment: Well, yes, it is what I started thinking that I pass some not existing roles in request. I thought I can pass whatever and if that whatever match on power Bi platform something, then it is fine, else - do nothing. Ok, thx for help. Now I know :)